# Why is it more difficult to turn the steering wheel of a stationary car than a moving car?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, everyday-life, speed

I believe anyone who has driven a car without power steering has noticed this effect. I am not able to find a justifiable argument online. My thought process suggested it must have to do something with the static friction in the case of a moving car which provides it a centripetal acceleration, but I am not sure. A reasonable and complete argument will be much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that "centripetal acceleration" plays any role. Turning the steering wheel when the car is not moving puts considerable strain on the rubber tire treads where they meet the pavement. I'd _guess_ that turning the wheel is easier when the car is rolling because the rolling motion of the tires continually brings new _unstrained_ rubber into contact with the pavement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a car's steering wheel get lighter with increasing speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465280/)

Comment: the steering and suspension geometry of the front end of the car uses a tiny bit of the car's forward motion to make the wheel a little easier to turn. That assistance is lost when the car is standing still.